# OpenSUSE - get device ID (or name)

Tags: input, device, opensuse, wacom

I have 8 events in /dev/input: event0, event1 ... event7. I only need one of them for touchscreen config, but I don't know how to get the device event. The touchscreen is a WACOM serial one!

Is there any way I could get a list of device names and their matching /dev/input/event* node?

Answer (score 0):

The udevadm command will be showed that your WACOM device is allocated which event device. ( I'm try on The Ubuntu 11.04 )

Please type as below in your terminal and search "wacom" or "Wacom".

/sbin/udevadm info -export-db | less

If you found the matched keyword, focus "N: ..." column.
Maybe the column is written by "input/event*".